# Access Denied while trying to create AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm just starting to learn AWS am trying to create an S3 bucket through the 'Get Started' button on the S3 console. After naming my bucket, selecting the region, and altering nothing on the 'configure options' and 'set permissions' pages, when I go to create the bucket I get an error saying 'Access Denied.'

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Your aws account does not have permission to create bucket.

Comment: How are you logging into the AWS Account? Is it your own personal AWS Account, or have you been provided credentials on a corporate AWS Account? If the latter, it is possible that you have not been granted sufficient permissions to create the bucket. You should chat with whoever provided the credentials. If it is your _own_ AWS Account, then this should not be happening.

Answer (score 0):

when accessing AWS S3 as a user you should have the correct ownership or bucket policy attached to the bucket. If you are accessing it via the CLI, you need to make sure your credientials are correct.

Here is a troubleshooting document from AWS to help with Access Denied responses

[troubleshoot aws s3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)

Here is some basic getting started documentation for helping with aws s3 cli configuration [aws s3 cli commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no too much information to dig so that I guess the account you log in to AWS is not Root Account(which is the one you register on AWS and it should be an e-mail address).

If you are login as an IAM user then you should be no permissions in the beginning. You should try it again with Root account or grant your IAM user corresponding permission.

Comment: https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-LC5_wRdrqHuVGrRtwIb/Access%20Denied%20in%20S3,%20creating%20bucket